# Giving multiple conditions in for loop - Groovy

Tags: for-loop, groovy

I was searching for "How to give multiple conditions in a for loop?". In "GROOVY" But there are no direct answers given.

I want to check two conditions in one ‘for’ loop in groovy.

environment and language are ArrayLists
Their size is not the same. Say for example,
environment.size()=3

language.size()=2

so, i want `i` to run from 0 to 2
and ‘j’ to run from 0 to 1

`for(i=0, j=0 ; i<environment.size() || j<language.size(); i++, j++)`

I am not able to use multiple conditions in "for loop" and iterate it over in groovy. Any workaround.

I need to iterate over 2 arrayList without using multiple loops. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: what is the issue you are facing ? Moreover, if you have OR logic then doesn't it go out of bounds if you still access one of the arrayList inside for loop ?

Comment: "org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/home/cg/root/3888268/main.groovy: 6: unexpected token: i "

And no, I don't get out of bound exception.

I need to iterate over 2 arrayList without using multiple loops. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here? Do you want to zip the two lists or do you want to get all permutations?

Comment: @cfrick, let's say I have to iterate over 2 arrayList without using multiple loops. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: So you want to zip the two lists? Unless this is some homework to learn about loops you will get way better answers, if you could be convinced to tell what this is good for and what result you expect (or what you plan to do inside the loop)

Comment: Agree with @cfrick here, we can not give you a relevant answer unless you tell us the problem  you are trying to solve. Do you want to iterate and see each element in both lists exactly once? Do you want to iterate and see each element once, but stop when you have reached the end of the shortest list? Why the "without multiple loops" constraint? Etc etc. We are happy to help, but can only do so if you describe your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the `def` for `i` and `j` in the `for` loop.

```
for(def i=0, j=0 ; i<environment.size() || j<language.size(); i++, j++) {
//  ~~~
```

Please note, that this feature is only possible since [Groovy 3.0 with
the new Parrot
parser](https://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-3.0.html)

> do-while loops; enhanced (now supporting commas) classic for loops,
> e.g. `for(int i = 0, j = 10; i < j; i++, j--) {..}`)

Also using for loops like this is quite rare in idiomatic groovy code.
Unless you want to break early there are better tools to e.g. zip two
lists.